# running kubectl create command from inside a shell script

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to call `kubectl create -n $test_namespace -f <absolute-path-to-tea-rc-file>.yaml` from a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

current_dir=$(pwd)
echo "current_dir is $current_dir"
parentdir="$(dirname "$current_dir")"
echo $parentdir
kubectl create -n $test_namespace -f $parentdir/deployment/common/tea-rc.yaml
```

It gives error as below:

```
Bhagyashrees-MacBook-Pro:execution_controller bhagyashree$ sh test.sh 
current_dir is /Users/bhagyashree/Documents/FDrepo/armada-ingress-ctl-test/execution_controller
/Users/bhagyashree/Documents/FDrepo/armada-ingress-ctl-test
error: unknown command "/Users/bhagyashree/Documents/FDrepo/armada-ingress-ctl-test/deployment/common/tea-rc.yaml"
See 'kubectl create -h' for help and examples.
```

the same command works when it is executed from a terminal.
`kubectl create -n testnamespace -f /Users/bhagyashree/Documents/FDrepo/armada-ingress-ctl-test/deployment/common/tea-rc.yaml`

What I am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because the variable $test_namespace has not been set.

If you change the last line to `echo "kubectl create -n $test_namespace -f $parentdir/deployment/common/tea-rc.yaml"` you'll see what it's trying to run, it will look like `kubctl create -n  -f /path/to/dir/deployment/common/tea-rc.yaml`. The Namespace can not be left blank.

You could also try adding a line like `echo $test_namespace` to check.

Comment: yes. The namespace was passed blank. Once I set the namespace, I am able to create the resource with above syntax.
Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked, would you mind marking it as the correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: Done. Marked it as correct answer. Thanks again @Simon

Comment: can you also explain how can we run the contents of yaml from shell not using file?

Comment: Hey Simon do you mind if I ask you to share the final script/solution? Thank you